# Android case statement help

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make my case statement open up a different class depending on what button is pressed. I got this working fine for one button but am unsure how to proceed for two buttons.

Heres my code so far:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.about_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.reminderList_button:
        Intent i = new Intent (this, ReminderListActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    }

}
```

This gives an error because I'm reusing the local variable (i) - if anyone could let me know how to do this properly it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare the variable `i` before the switch statement. This is especially preferable to "scoping" if you plan to use the variable `i` after the switch statement:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.about_button:
        i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        break;
    case R.id.reminderList_button:
        i = new Intent (this, ReminderListActivity.class);
        break;
    }
    startActivity(i);
    ...; // other statements using `i'
}
```

Comment: Any reason why this is better than scoping? just cleaner and less code?

Comment: @user319940 Yes, as I said: if you want to use the variable `i` later, after the switch statement, then you will not be able to do so if you have made `i` local to the scope within the switch statement. And regardless, you will have less duplicated code if you move out `startActivity(i)` after the switch statement, too. :)

Comment: More error-prone if you don't handle the default case though. Be sure to initialize and check i, at least.

Comment: Yep it through up an error about it not being initialized so I just made it = null - seems to work OK. Thanks :).

Comment: You still need to check i for null before using it though, or else your app will crash if getId() returns something you didn't handle.

Comment: Thanks, EboMike! Updated with initialization, but omitted validity check for `i`.

Comment: I'm quite new to all this - what would be a good method for checking the validity of i?

Comment: `if (i != null)` should cover you.

Answer (score 1):

Scope it.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.about_button:
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    case R.id.reminderList_button:
        {
            Intent i = new Intent (this, ReminderListActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! seems to be just what I was looking for :D

Comment: IMHO: At this point it would be more readable to create methods startAboutActivity(), startReminderListActivity()... etc.